# Reading an image and storing it into an array in c# xaml

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, xaml, image-processing

I am trying to open an image file (either JPEG or JPG) and store the image into an array in c# xaml. Although I can open the file and convert the file into a bitmap image, I cannot store it into an array. Here is my code:

```
    public int row;
    public int column;
    public byte[] bmp;
    public byte[,] data;
    public double width;
    public double height;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create OpenFileDialog
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        // Set filter for file extension and default file extension
        dlg.FileName = "";
        //dlg.DefaultExt = ".jpg";
        dlg.Filter = "JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif";

        // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            string filename = dlg.FileName;
            bmp = readfile(filename);
            int x = bmp.Length;
            data = new byte[(int)Math.Sqrt(x), (int)Math.Sqrt(x)];
            row = 0;
            column = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                row = i % (int)Math.Sqrt(x);
                column = i /(int)Math.Sqrt(x);
                data[row, column] = bmp[i];
            }



        }
        }
    public byte[] readfile(String filename)
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        Uri uri = new Uri(filename);
        bitmapImage.UriSource = uri;
        img.Source = bitmapImage;

        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();              
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
        encoder.Save(memStream);
        return memStream.GetBuffer();
        width = bitmapImage.Width;
        height = bitmapImage.Height;
```

Comment: What happens that is stopping you from adding it? also you have unreachable code in your `readfile`

Comment: I get this error: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. And I see this error at line:   encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));

Comment: No idea what exactly you are doing there, but using the square root of the buffer size for the dimensions of a two-dimensional array doesn't make any sense. Besides that, you should use `MemoryStream.ToArray` instead of `GetBuffer` to get the actual bytes, as the allocated buffer may be larger than the actually encoded buffer. You would typically also use `File.ReadAllBytes` to get the bytes of an image file.

Comment: and how do i do that? Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: It's not clear *what exactly* you are trying to achieve. If it's all about getting the image buffer as a byte array, use `File.ReadAllBytes`.

Comment: If you are trying to get the pixel values as a two-dimensional array, what are you going to do with it?

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why are you doing it in such a complicated way.
If you want to create a BitmapImage and you have a path to the file system why not use:

```
BitmapImage bImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(dlg.FileName));
```

Then you can store the image in array/list easily by having a list/array:

```
List<BitmapImage> _images = new List<BitmapImage>();

_images.Add(bImage);
```

**Beware that storing large images in arrays/list can be quite memory consuming.**

EDIT

If you want to simply store byte array use:

```
byte[] buff = File.ReadAllBytes(dlg.FileName)
```

Note that `byte[]` contains 1 file so if you want to store multiple files use either 2 dymensional `byte[]` (`byte[][]`) or `List<byte[]>`.

To get height and width of the image:

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName);
Console.Write("Width: " + img.Width + ", Height: " + img.Height);
```

Comment: and how to i convert this into a byte array

Comment: yes i want to store a 2 dimensional array since i need to have the width and height info of the image. How should i do that?

Comment: 2 dimentional array allows you to store multiple files but it will not give you any information about the file itself. The bytes are NOT organized in a way that 100x100px image would be stored in byte[100][100] array.